# AKS algorithm: How to do the polynomial modulo part.

Tags: polynomials, primality-test

I have a question about the last part of the AKS algorithm. I already know how to compute $p \pmod{(x^r-1,n)}$ for a given polynomial $p$ but only once $p$ is in canonical form. In order for AKS to have the time complexity claimed it would be necessary to compute $(x+a)^n \pmod{(x^r,n)}$ without actually expanding $(x+a)^n$.

What's the trick for doing this? I've had a look at a few of the C++ implementations of AKS but I've generally been unable to find the relevant part of the code.

Comment: I've tried to edit the modulo stuff but did not understand what you were trying to write. If you explain, I'll edit the Latex mistakes.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test
by "p modulo (x^r - 1,n)" I meant the remainder when p is divided by both (x^r - 1) and n

Comment: That's a common false usage. $p \pmod{k}$ is a meaningless statement. For instance, in $a\equiv p \pmod{k}$, $\pmod{k}$ is not on the $\text{RHS}$ of the equivalence. It's about the whole equivalence. What I mean is, modulo is a property of an equivalence, not an operator. Anyway, even it's not an officially true statement, it would be more understandable after the Latex edit. You can use \pmod{} to show modulo in MathJax.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. On that subject, what's the actual term for the operator?

Comment: Do you mean what I meant with operator? A function with 2 inputs. I mean, you cannot define a function $f$ such as $f(p,k) = p \pmod{k}$, because a function should map one point to exactly one point. However, $\text{mod}$ does not create an exact output as $14 \equiv 9\pmod{5}$ and $14 \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$ are both true. Then, $\text{mod}$ equivalence is not a function, it's a relation. That's why you cannot just write $p\pmod{k}$, because it does not have an exact value.

Comment: Probably the best way of saying what you meant with $p \pmod{(x^r-1,n)}$ is saying "$s$ where $s$ is the smallest non-negative integer satisfying $p \equiv s \pmod{(x^r-1,n)}$"

Comment: That's what I meant.